# Is there a medium format film scanner that has an automatic feed?

Tags: scanning, medium-format, automation, negative-scanner

I have a huge stack of old medium format negatives, I want to somewhat automate the scan (there are 1000 or so!) I'm wondering if there are any medium format scanners have some sort or automated feed.

Comment: Just noting that for the scanners I am familiar with, the automated feeds are only on 35mm.  I am not aware of any medium format scanner that can handle spools or [automatic slide feeders](http://www.amazon.com/Nikon-SF-210-Auto-Slide-Feeder/dp/B0001AVVRA) ($1.5k?! When I got one a decade ago it was only $400 or so) the way that exists for 35mm.

Comment: Interesting I found an older epson scanner that has a business card feed, I wonder if I could re-purpose that it or if it would damage the negatives.

Comment: It is unlikely that it will have the necessary setup to scan *through* the media rather than light reflected off the media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the minilab scanners do (such as Fuji Frontier and Noritsu). An older one with acceptable resolution and speed can be had for around 3k. There are online vendors specialized in recycling and reselling these machines (see [here](http://youtu.be/luZtl7wx3ww)).

I haven't heard of any consumer level scanner with this feature. But even if there is, it doesn't solve much of a problem for you, because each 120 film contains only a few shots, after which you will have to reload the scanner.

Instead of that you can get a high end desktop scanner that takes two strips of MF film and buy an additional film holder as well. Then you can load one holder while the other one is in the scanner. So, you will load the scanner twice for each 120 film roll. This is only twice the loading effort that would be needed with a completely automatic system with roll feeder!